# How to put a Vector into an intent.extra?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-intent

I've started to write a small app for android. It looks very nice, but there is one thing I don't understand.

I've created a new intent in the activity A and I've added a serialized vector `intent.putExtra("key", vector)`. On the called activity B I'm doing this: `Vector<ItemModel> items = (Vector<ItemModel>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key")`. This line causes a `ClassCastException`. Does anyone know why? Please help me :-)

Here is the source of the two activities and of the `ItemModel`:

ItemModel:

```
public class ItemModel implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1772392719565658730L;
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String quantity;
    public int status;

}
```

ShoppingListActivity (A):

```
   public void onClickItems(final View v){
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this,ItemListActivity.class);

        Vector<ItemModel> v1 = new Vector<ItemModel>();
        ItemModel item = new ItemModel();

        item.name = "Tomaten";
        item.quantity = "400g";
        item.id = 12;
        item.status = 0;
        v1.add(item);

        item = new ItemModel();
        item.name = "Bohnen";
        item.quantity = "150g";
        item.id = 13;
        item.status = 0;
        v1.add(item);

        item = new ItemModel();
        item.name = "Schokolade";
        item.quantity = "5 Tafeln";
        item.id = 17;
        item.status = 0;
        v1.add(item);

        intent.putExtra("ShoppingList", v1);

        startActivity(intent);
```

ItemListActivity (B):

```
   public class ItemListActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ITEMSLIST);
        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Vector<ItemModel> items = (Vector<ItemModel>) extras.getSerializable("ShoppingList");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> itemMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

Comment: it did not work for me as i use List<SoapObject>  too bad any suggestions .. initially i made the web service request on the second activity

Answer (score 5):

Anything that implements List and Serializable is internally turned into an ArrayList. So it might go in as a Vector but it comes out as an ArrayList. It's probably better to treat it as just a List<> at both ends in the putter and getter.

As a general rule, don't use Vector either. All the methods are synchronized which makes it less efficient than an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

bit confused... but sure you didn't need `Vector<ItemModel>` instead of `Vector` for your class cast?

Which type is returned by `getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key")`?

Comment: Thank you for the _very_ fast reply :-). You are right with Vector<ItemModel> and it was just a mistake in my post (as you can see in the listings)

I've asked android which class is be returned and android told me "ArrayList". Well, I didn't expect this... but it works fine with ArrayList.

Thank you very much for the very fast answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: replace

```
Vector<ItemModel> v1 = new Vector<ItemModel>();
```

with

```
List<ItemModel> v1 = new ArrayList<ItemModel>();
```

and

```
Vector<ItemModel> items = (Vector<ItemModel>) extras.getSerializable("ShoppingList");
```

with

```
List<ItemModel> items = (List<ItemModel>) extras.getSerializable("ShoppingList");
```

Declaring v1 and items as List objects should be enough, the change to `ÁrrayList` would just show if there was some strange issue with the Vector classes.

According to the doc I see no reason why it shouldn't work with the `Vector` class too. Maybe, by chance, you imported different Vector classes, so you could double check your import statements if all classes import `java.lang.Vector` only.