# Passing vector, getting ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, vector, arraylist

I am trying to pass a vector from one activity to another as:

```
Vector<Vector<MovieAndTimesEntry>> vector=MovieAndTimesEntry.getLineup(mvs);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ExpandableListViewActitivy.class);
intent.putExtra("lineups", vector);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `ExpandableListViewActivity` I try to get this value as:

```
    Vector<Vector<MovieAndTimesEntry>> vector;
    vector=((Vector<Vector<MovieAndTimesEntry>>) extras.get("lineups"));//ExpandableListViewActitivy.java:33
```

But I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MovieHop/com.example.MovieHop.ExpandableListViewActitivy}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
        at com.example.MovieHop.ExpandableListViewActitivy.onCreate(ExpandableListViewActitivy.java:33)
```

So what's wrong here?

Comment: Why use `Vector` in 2014? That is the first problem imho

Comment: @fge But whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like when you call putExtra its converting your Vector into an ArrayList: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3531800/2824919

Answer (score 2):

Try doing in in this way. New collections are better than vector. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/08/java-best-practices-vector-arraylist.html

```
List<List<MovieAndTimesEntry>> vector=MovieAndTimesEntry.getLineup(mvs);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ExpandableListViewActitivy.class);
intent.putExtra("lineups", vector);
startActivity(intent);
```

then

```
List<List<MovieAndTimesEntry>> vector;
vector=((List<List<MovieAndTimesEntry>>) extras.get("lineups"));
```

Comment: It gives an incompatiable type compile time error. But I got your point.So an upvote seems perfect. I would surely try to implement this using your idea.

Comment: Sory for mistake ;) it was from hurrying up in responsing :)

Comment: I think your MovieAndTimesEntry.getLineup(mvs) should reutrn sth with List interface.

Comment: It returns Vector<Vector<MovieAndTimesEntry>> vector. I think it has to be replaced by arraylist everywhere.

Comment: Yes yes. Do the replacement.

Comment: but this does not work for me. You need to edit this answer to replace all List by ArrayList.

Comment: Array list implements List interface so there is compatibility in that code. I don't know why it is not working for you but when you declare your variable simply vector there is strong need to do in as much abstract way as it is possible. So ArrayList is implementation of List interface so any ArrayList object(that object implements List interface) should be equal to List and you can assign arrayList reference to List.